# Leeb and Pötscher, how is the required sample size calculated?

Tags: model-selection, inference

I'm reading through Leeb and Pötscher's *Model Selection and inference: facts and fiction* (2005) ([Link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3533623?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents))

On page 28 they perform a calculation, but I'm not sure how they derived the result. The state:

> Furthermore, we can also calculate, for given $\beta \not = 0$, how many
>   data points are needed such that the probability of selecting the correct (i.e. the unrestricted)  model is at least 0.9, say. With $c=\sqrt{\log n}$ as in Figure 1, we obtain: If $\beta/\sigma_\beta = 1$, then a sample of size $n \geq 8$ is needed; if $\beta/\sigma_\beta = \frac{1}{2}$, one needs $n\geq 42, \ldots$

Here the probabilty of selecting the unrestricted model is given as by formula **(3)** in the paper:
$$ P(\hat M = U) = 1-\left\{\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\beta}{\sigma_\beta}+c
\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\beta}{\sigma_\beta}-c\right)\right\}$$

If I calculate these probabilities as above then:
$$
1-\left\{\Phi(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{\log n}) - \Phi(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{\log n}) \right\}
$$
for $n=8$ this results in
$$
1-\left\{\Phi(\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{\log 8}) - \Phi(\sqrt{8}-\sqrt{\log 8}) \right\} \approx 0.97 \not = 0.9
$$
een worse, if I try $n=5$ then the probability is about $0.92$, how did Leeb and Pötscher reach the 8 instead of using 5? (why being so *conservative*)?

The calculation with $\beta/\sigma_{\beta} = 0.5$ and $n=42$ yield a probability of approx $0.98$, again the much lower $n = 25$ results in 0.91. Why not state $n\geq 25$?